# GWT - RemoteEventServiceServlet - domain error

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to make [this example](http://luck0r.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/gwteventservice-hello-world/); I just faced a strange error which happens when sendMessage(String msg) method is invoked

the stack trace says

> Domain [ERROR] Client-Error: Error on register client for domain!
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404
>   ...

I am not pretty sure where the error comes from :S

the EntryPoint code is

```
public class ImageViewer implements EntryPoint {
    /**
     * The domain to which we want to register our listener to
     */
    private static final Domain DOMAIN = DomainFactory.getDomain("my_domain");



    private RichTextArea echoTextArea;
    private RichTextArea sendTextArea;
    private ImageViewerBL imageViewerBL=new ImageViewerBL();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

        FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        rootPanel.add(flowPanel, 10, 10);
        flowPanel.setSize("392px", "384px");

        Label lblEcho = new Label("Echo : ");
        flowPanel.add(lblEcho);

        echoTextArea= new RichTextArea();
        flowPanel.add(echoTextArea);

        Label lblInput = new Label("Input : ");
        flowPanel.add(lblInput);

        sendTextArea = new RichTextArea();
        flowPanel.add(sendTextArea);

        HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        flowPanel.add(horizontalPanel);

        Button btnSend = new Button("SEND");
        btnSend.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                imageViewerBL.sendMessage(sendTextArea.getText());
            }
        });
        horizontalPanel.add(btnSend);

        this.initBL();
}

    RemoteEventServiceFactory theEventServiceFactory;
    RemoteEventService theEventService;
    private void initBL()
    {

        /**
         * Create an EventService
         */
        theEventServiceFactory = RemoteEventServiceFactory.getInstance();
        theEventService = theEventServiceFactory.getRemoteEventService();

        /**
         * Register our listener to the domain
         */
        theEventService.addListener(DOMAIN, new MyListener(){
            public void onMyEvent(MyEvent event){
                /**
                 * Get the message from the event and append it to the allready received messages
                 */
                echoTextArea.setText( echoTextArea.getText() + event.getMessage() + "n" );
            }
        });

    }
}
```

the ImageViewerBL code is

```
public class ImageViewerBL implements IsSerializable {

    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        TestServiceAsync service=(TestServiceAsync)GWT.create(TestService.class);
        AsyncCallback callback=new AsyncCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                Window.alert("Message has been sent");

            }

        };
    }
}
```

All the rest code is totally the same as the example shows. Help me to find out where the error is coming from.

With Firebug net I can see this

as post:

> 7|0|8|http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/|96C13DAC0140CBCE9399464D9D221B3D|de.novanic.eventservice.client.event.service.EventService|register|de.novanic.eventservice.client.event.domain.Domain|de.novanic.eventservice.client.event.filter.EventFilter|de.novanic.eventservice.client.event.domain.DefaultDomain/240262385|my_domain|1|2|3|4|2|5|6|7|8|0|

and response says this :

> Error 404 NOT_FOUND
>
> ### HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> ```
> NOT_FOUND
> ```
>
> RequestURI=/com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/gwteventservice
>
> *[Powered by
>   Jetty://](http://jetty.mortbay.org/)*

Concerning the app run - the web.xml is

```
<web-app>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>ImageViewer.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.project.server.TestServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/TestService</url-pattern>       
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

on sendMessage() method invoke the dev mode throws this:

> 00:00:38,360 [ERROR] Client-Error: Error on processing event!
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call
>   failed on the server; see server log for details  at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)

and the servlet method code is:

```
@Override
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        /**
         * We dont save the incomming messages on the server. We just send an MyEvent to all
         * registered Listeners on the Domain.
         */
//      try {
//          this.addEvent(DOMAIN, new MyEvent(message));
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      





}
```

...I commented the code which causes error 500; So if not running the commented code error 500 id not thrown; So the problem is somewhere in addEvent() method but I am not sure what exactly causes the problem :S

What is really can be wrong with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Status code is 404, meaning resource not found; this could mean that the corresponding servlet is not installed on the server, hasn't started up or that the target URL is incorrect.

Comment: But the PushServerServiceImpl is in my web.xml; so what else may missing?

Comment: Just because it's there doesn't mean that  a) it's receiving anything, b) the client is requesting the correct address... use firebug or smth equivalent to see what request the browser is making.

Comment: But it should receive something right? Is the client registration goes wrong or something? What exactly should I look for? What servlet is not mentioned in my web.xml then? Not a project one but a lib's one or something?

Comment: Thank for your advice for Firebug but What should I use in Firebug to lead for your advice as check "what request the browser is taking"?

Comment: OK I used NET tab to see browser request but the information I get is quite abstract as for me :( I'd like to know your opinion about this data; I placed modifications in my question please see my question edit

Comment: Well, it does receive the error message that the server can't find any resource at the location /com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/gwteventservice. Now, I would heartily recommend that you re-read the GWT RPC tutorial, because it looks like your servlet is not in its proper location, or that the request is made to the wrong address

Comment: I checked thank you; The missing servlet it seems to be in lib not a project one. But problem doesn't stop with it :) Each server request breaks service listener or something :S I mean the ImageViewerBL sendMessage method invoke makes error 500 ... The example shows to use Void in return but GWT 2.3 in my case says that returning Object is not proper thing so I had to return a String type;  Is it an error to return something in onSuccess(String) method in case of RemoteEventServiceServlet? Can a return methor cause threads conflict or something in that case?

Comment: You really need to check the debug log of your servlet container, if a request sends response code 500 the most likely cause is an exception withing the server-side code. You can always return void from an RPC call, the return type in your client code will be Void (notice the capital V), the return type in the interface should be void (lower-case v). Now, what is the path part of the page you are loading?

Comment: There is only one page I have iy is the welcome page; I just added web.xml to my question. Should I show the gwt.xml too?

Comment: See, here is your problem: the requested URL is /com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/gwteventservice but the registered servlet is at the URL /com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/TestService (which is the last case I mention at my reply) - either move the servlet to th expected location or instruct GWT that the location is non-standard.

Comment: I didn't create some another servlet as the TestService; You mean some lib's servlet I didn't create?

Comment: Look into your web.xml. See the paths there?

Comment: I didn't write paths manually. All was generated automatically as remote service "TestService" was created; Is there an error? Actually I checked the sendMessage(String) method (before switching the event listener ) to return a value back to client and it worked :S ; I mean expression like String sendMessage(String message){return "Hello World";} do worked fine;